# Pretty print a tree in a console shell in Java

Tags: java, tree

If you are working on trees one of the most useful method to implement is a clear way to print it out it, in the following my solution to print a tree in Java:

```
public void printTree(NodeRB tree, String indent, boolean print_leaf) {
    if(tree == NILL) {
        System.out.print((print_leaf?indent+"   |-+*\n":""));
    } else { 
        indent += "   ";
        if(tree.p == NILL || tree.p == null) {
            printTree(tree.right, indent + " ", print_leaf);
            System.out.print(indent + "+" + tree.value + "\n");
            printTree(tree.left, indent + " ", print_leaf);
        }else if(tree.p.right==tree) {
            printTree(tree.right, indent + " ", print_leaf);
            System.out.print(indent + "|+" + tree.value + "\n");
            printTree(tree.left, indent + "|", print_leaf);
        }
        else {  
            printTree(tree.right, indent + "|", print_leaf);
            System.out.print(indent + "|+" + tree.value + "\n");
            printTree(tree.left, indent + " ", print_leaf);

        }
    }

}
```

Someone has proposal to improve it?

Comment: If the code already works, you should post this on Code Review.

Comment: Stackoverflow [encourages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) answering your own questions, however only in the format where you formulate the question-part as a question and put the answer in as an answer. This way other answers can stand besides yours.

Comment: Since you added the "code-review" tag, did you read its description? :)

Comment: I can't comment on your code since as has already been pointed out that would be a matter for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but I'd like to add 2 things: 1) you might want to "print" into a `StringBuilder` etc. instead of `System.out` so that one could feed the generated string to some file, a logging framework like log4j etc. 2) It seems like you add a lot of `|` which I (and that's a personal opinion) find rather annoying for deeper trees. You might want to allow for some configuration of that as in many cases some nice indentation would be sufficient already.